# How would I add points to a specific user in my database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created and app with a working login and registration. When someone logs in and presses a button there username is sent to a Earn.php file that is connected to my database that has a points column in it. My problem lies with adding, lets say 5 points to the users specific account.

Example: Username sent to php file from app> then the php file takes that specific username and add 5 points to its point column in the database. Like 5+5=10

What I have now:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id177667_root", "***", "id177667_loginb");
$username = $_POST["username"];
?>
```

Sorry if this is a lot to ask for, I very knew at this! Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This has a simple solution. You can use update statement:

```
$q = "UPDATE TableName SET points = points + 5 WHERE username_column ='".$username."'";
$r = mysqli_query($con , $q) or die();
```

Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: `$username` will more than likely be a string, so what you posted will fail `WHERE username_column =".$username;`.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake, i fixed it.